# requestAnimationFrame animation is running slower and slower

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, requestanimationframe

1、I want to make a loop animation.The point is createRadialGradient() which is changing.  The detail for the code like:

```
(function(){
  var ctx = null;

 window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
    return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequsestAnimationFrame ||
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function(callback){
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000/60);
    };
})();

var star = {
    radius: 0,
    step: 2*Math.PI/60,
    canvas: document.querySelector("canvas"),
    init: function(){
        ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        this.animate();

    },
    radialGradient: function(){
        if(this.radius>=2*Math.PI){
            this.radius = 0;
        }
        var radGrad=ctx.createRadialGradient((Math.cos(this.radius)*80+250),(Math.sin(this.radius)*80+250),15,250,250,1800);
            radGrad.addColorStop(0.0,"white");
            radGrad.addColorStop(0.05,"yellow");
        this.radius += this.step;
        return radGrad;
    },
    draw: function(){
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
        ctx.moveTo(76,197);
        ctx.lineTo(421,197);  
        ctx.lineTo(143,399);  
        ctx.lineTo(248,71);  
        ctx.lineTo(356,399);  
        ctx.lineTo(76,197);
        ctx.fillStyle = this.radialGradient();
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.lineWidth = 6;
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.fill();
    },
    animate: function(){
        star.play = requestAnimFrame(star.animate);
        star.draw();
    }

}; 

window.onload = function(){
    star.init();
}

}());
```

2、OK, when the code is running, the animate is excuting slower and slower.So, how can I fix it? Please give me a hand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are forgetting to create a new path for the canvas 2D api each frame.

To start a new path use `ctx.beginPath()`. The function closePath() does not actually close the current path, it simply joins the last lineTo, etc end point to the previous moveTo. The path is still active.

Add

```
ctx.beginPath();
```

just after clearRect in the draw function and that will fix the problem as at the moment you keep adding to the path giving the render more and more work.